# In a characteristic zero field, can we get every element in the field by summing the identity element with itself

Tags: field-theory, linear-transformations

> In a characteristic zero field, can we get every element in the field
>   by summing the identity element with itself ?

I'm studying linear algebra right now, and in the book of *Linear Algebra by Werner Greub*, it says that $f^\mu (x_v)  = \delta_\mu^v$ is a basis for $L(E)$ in the page 77, so from the previous theorem, I get the idea that the identity element in a characteristic zero field is **sort of** a basis itself, is this correct ?If so, how can we prove it ? If it is not, can you explain the relation between the section 2.31 and 2.32 in the [book](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4)

Comment: For every field $K$, you have that $K$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $1$, and its basis is $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: Are you saying that $1/2 \in Q$ is a sum of finitely many copies of $1$? I'm not sure what "infinitely many" means in this context, as there is no topology.

Comment: @user49640 a nice counter example :)

Comment: @user49640 while trying to be clear, I guess I was vague.

Comment: It is true, as Crostul says, that $\{1\}$ is a basis for $K$ as a $K$-vector space. But what you seem to be asking is whether $\{1\}$ is a generating set for $K$ as a $Z$-module. That will never be true in characteristic zero, because $K$ will always contain a subfield isomorphic to $Q$.

Comment: @user49640 No, I'm exactly asking what Crostul says, but I just mix the $Z-module$ with linear combinations.Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is *no* field of characteristic $0$ such that every element of the field can be obtained summing the identity element with itself a finite number of times. And what does it mean to add it to itself an infinite number of times?

Comment: I edited that part, sorry for the vagueness, I was just trying to be clear in my head.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by there is no field of characteristic zero ? I mean characteristic of a field the additive degree of the identity, so for example in $R$, how doesn't the characteristic is not 0 ?

Comment: @Leth That is just part of the sentence. What I wrote was that there is no field of characteristic $0$ such that every element of the field can be obtained summing the identity element with itself.

Comment: You are right, I missed that "such that" part after reading "there is no field of characteristic 0" :)